# Extjs5 , resolving dependency in the proxy while loading model

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have a proxy in my Model that is trying to read a configuration

```
proxy:
{
    type:'rest',
    url:MyApp.Config.MY_SERVICE,     <-- Problem
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'contact'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    },
```

}

The below config class is loaded initially in app.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Config',
{       
alias:'Config',     
statics:
{       
    MY_SERVICE: 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/myservice',
}
}
```

The error that I get is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MY_SERVICE' of undefined (anonymous function)
```

The exact same code works from within the proxy of my store.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a load-order problem. Because you are using the static variable during the definition of your model, there is a chance that your config class hasn't been defined yet, even if you've defined it within your `app.js` file.

The `MyApp.Config` class won't be defined until the `Ext.define` call is fully processed. But the definition of the model needs it - you're building an object that uses that class as part of the call to *it's* `Ext.define`. This means that the reference needs to be ready when the file is read in.

One solution would be to replace the object with a function - e.g.:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyModel', function() {
  return {
   ...
   proxy: {
    type:'rest',
    url: MyApp.Config.MY_SERVICE,
   }
  }
})
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will defer creating the object until later in the sequence, possibly giving the `app.js` code a chance to define the `MyApp.Config` object.

This is still dependent on getting the order correct, however. The easiest way you can do that is to make your application class require your config class - these requires should get processed before the models, etc. Your config class should be the first thing required.